# is possible to invoke a function when going to previous page using history.go(-1);

Tags: javascript, mern

I want to invoke a function when I go previous page, I try window.load

```
const isUpdated = () => {
    const profileUpdated = localStorage.getItem('profileUpdated')
    if (profileUpdated) {
        let res = JSON.parse(profileUpdated)
        localStorage.removeItem('profileUpdated');
        alertBanner.innerText = res.message;
        alertBanner.parentElement.classList = 'alert green-alert';
    }
}

window.onload = isUpdated()
```

It is a vanilla js project, so separated Html when profile update I want to go back and show success message.

Comment: `window.onload = isUpdated()` <-- that is wrong

Comment: @epascarello can you explain why it's not working, I just try isUpdated() without any event listeners but not working

Comment: Have you tried just calling `isUpdated()` in ordinary way, like on page load?

Comment: `window.onload = isUpdated()` -> `window.onload = isUpdated`

Comment: mark your `<script ...>` as [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) and just call `isUpdated()`, not `window.onload = isUpdated()`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans not invoking the second time I'm trying to go back to profile page without refreshing

Comment: @Justinas yes it not working on second time when I go back because of cashing

Comment: It sounds like you want history state management rather than "actual" page navigation, for which you'll want to read up on the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and how to properly use `pushState` and `onpopstate`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I could find the answer. I came up with this ```setInterval(isUpdated, 1000)```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Now it's working but I know it bad practice

Comment: It's not just bad practice, it's both unnecessary and "not going to work if your tab isn't in focus" (because intervals get throttled for content that the user can't see). Taking the take to read up on, and then implement, using the history API is going to both solve this problem far better, and teach you something you can use for other purposes too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I check the history api doc, but I don't get it how to implement on this problem I implement exactly like doc and that not worked.